# angular using an observable within an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I am making an expense manager webapp with angular 6. My database is on firebase. I am using the angularfire2 lib to retrieve and update the data.

the database is designed as follows

[image: Database design]

the function to get a category is

```
getCategory(uid:String,categorykey:string):Observable<any> 
   {

return this.afdb.object(`users/${uid}/categories/${categorykey}`)
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(map(c=>({key:c.payload.key,...c.payload.val()})));}
```

the function that returns observable with an array of expenses is

```
getExpensesWithKeys(uid:String):Observable<any>{
return this.afdb.list(users/${uid}/expenses)
.snapshotChanges()
.pipe(
  map(changes =>
  changes.map(c => 
({key:c.payload.key,...c.payload.val()}))
  )
);
 }
```

In my component I can get my expenses as

```
expenses:Expense[];
getExpensesWithKey("userid-123")
.subscribe(expenses=>this.expenses=expenses)
```

and any category as

```
category:Category;
getCategory("userid-123",expenses[0].category)
.subscribe(category=>this.category=category);
```

I want to create an observable that gets the expenses array and returns the category for each expense which i can push into an array of categories.
I've been racking my brain to combine the two observables with all kinds of rxjs operaters but to no avail.

Would really appreciate some help.

edit:
Just wanted to add a few methods I tried already. 
One method I tried was

```
this.getExpensesWithKeys("user-123")
.pipe(mergeMap(expenses=>
expenses.map(expense=>
this.getCategory("user-123",expense.category)))).subscribe(console.log);
```

but it just emitting an array of Observables. How can i get the category objects and push them into an array?

Another method I tried

```
this.rtdbService.getExpensesWithKeys("user-123")
.pipe(map(expenses=>
   expenses.map(expense=>expense.category)))
   .pipe(mergeMap(ids=>
this.rtdbService.getCategory("user-123",ids)))
.subscribe(console.log);
```

This is only emitting the keys of the categories.

I also tried the below provided answer as well which is not emitting anything.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution

```
  getExpensewithCategories(uid:String):Observable<any>{
    ;
    let expwithCat$=this.getExpenses(uid).pipe(mergeMap(expenses =>{
      return expenses.map(expense => this.getCategory(uid,expense.category)
      .pipe(map(cat=>
        ({expensekey:expense.key,
          amount:expense.amount,
          date:expense.date,
          expcatkey:expense.category,
          categorykey:cat.key,
          color:cat.color,
          name:cat.name})
        )
      ))
   }
    }));

      return expwithCat$.pipe(mergeAll())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine `mergeMap` to chain observables with `forkJoin` to make several calls at once :

```js
getBothCategoryAndExpenses(uid) {
  return this.getExpensesWithKeys(uid).pipe(
    mergeMap(expenses => forkJoin(expenses.map(expense => this.getCategory(uid, expense.key)))
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: when I subscribe to this observable it is not returning anything. I have made minor changes in the method you created.
getBothCategoryAndExpenses(uid):Observable<any> {
  return this.getExpensesWithKeys(uid).pipe(
    mergeMap(expenses => forkJoin(expenses.map(expense => this.getCategory(uid, expense.category)))
 //expense.category holds the key of the category of that expense
    )
  );
}