# creating a observable function that has an observable inside it

Tags: angular, function, observable, angular2-observables

I am attempting to create an observable function that uses a observable inside it to do work.

```
verifyinteraction(action): Observable<any>{
return this.recaptchaV3Service.execute(action)
  .subscribe((token :any)=>{
    this.http.post(
      'http://127.0.0.1:8000/verify/recaptcha',
      token);
  });
```

}

the `verifyinteraction` function takes an `action`

this action is then passed to the `recaptchaV3Service`

then that service is subscribed to, and the result of that subscription is passed to my server, for work, then returned. The subscription of the `verifyinteraction`
is to be of the result of both of those actions.

However when I write this code I have this error

```
- error TS2740: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

 13     return this.recaptchaV3Service.execute(action)
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 14       .subscribe((token :any)=>{
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
... 
 17           token);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 18       });
    ~~~~~~~~~
```

its there an understanding of what I am missing? can someone clear this up for me please?

Comment: try reading for BehaviorSubject in rxjs https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc

Comment: @khizarsyed I read the article and have extracted zero value

Comment: looks like this post is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819588/angular-using-an-observable-within-an-observable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use one of the RxJS higher-order mapping operators (like `switchMap`, `concatMap` etc. - differences [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)) to map from one observable to another. Try the following

```js
verifyinteraction(action): Observable<any>{
  return this.recaptchaV3Service.execute(action).pipe(
    switchMap((token :any) => 
      this.http.post(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8000/verify/recaptcha',
        token
      );
    )
  );
}
```

Now the subscription call `this.verifyinteraction(action).subscribe(...)` will first trigger the `this.recaptchaV3Service.execute(action)` function and use the token from it to trigger the `this.http.post()` call.

But seeing that you're using authentication, I'd recommend you to use Angular [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to cache and add the token to HTTP requests instead of manually adding it to each request.